# Select word in VIM with ctrl+shift+arrow

Tags: vim, editor

Now, my config is: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Example_vimrc

with additional two lines in it:

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin
```

my sample text is:

```
foo.bar
```

how can i select **foo**, then **.bar** using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>

and **bar**, then **foo.** using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> ?

---

*<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Lelf</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> stop on dot char, like traditional editor, but when i use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd> - it stops only on whitespaces.*

vim version: 7.4
os: ubuntu 14.04

Comment: answer from [vim.wikia.com](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_C-Left_C-Right_behave_as_in_Windows)

Comment: I have the same problem and the answer below is not the real answer. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I don't remember anymore. vimrc is erased, I no longer use vim as my main editor

Answer (score 1):

The `Select-mode` (which will be enabled by `:behave mswin`) only "simulates" some behaviors of MS-Windows like editors. Just these movements `cursor keys, <End>, <Home>, <PageUp> and <PageDown>` with the shift key are expanding/collapsing current selection.

From `:help Select-mode`:

```
Commands in Select mode:
- Printable characters, <NL> and <CR> cause the selection to be deleted, and
  Vim enters Insert mode.  The typed character is inserted.
- Non-printable movement commands, with the Shift key pressed, extend the
  selection.  'keymodel' must include "startsel".
- Non-printable movement commands, with the Shift key NOT pressed, stop Select
  mode.  'keymodel' must include "stopsel".
- ESC stops Select mode.
- CTRL-O switches to Visual mode for the duration of one command. *v_CTRL-O*
- CTRL-G switches to Visual mode.
```

From `:help keymodel`:

```
... Using a shifted special key starts selection ... 
... Special keys in this context are the cursor keys, <End>, <Home>, 
<PageUp> and <PageDown>. ...
```

Try to read about it: `:help behave`, `:help Select-mode` and `:help keymodel`.

But, I **strongly** recommend you to learn about the "real" vim movements and commands and disable `:behave mswin`. It is actually way more powerful.

In your case you could simply press `veE` to select first `foo` then `foo.bar`. Or if your intention is to select the whole `foo.bar` at once even simpler, press `vW`.

Comment: dowvote for not answering the question